# Elements getting added to original List even if the new element is aded to other reference of LIst

Tags: java, list, collections

I am adding few elements to the original list and passing its reference to a new method. Inside the called method, I am again adding some more elements to the new reference of List and not returning the new reference of list to caller method. But, still the elements are getting added to original List. Can some one please explain how it is happening internally. How the changes in  new list is getting reflected in original list?

```
package listDemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListAddTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> fruitList = new ArrayList<String>();
      fruitList.add("Mango");
      fruitList.add("Banana");
      fruitList.add("Apple");
      System.out.println("Before addFruits :"+fruitList);
      addFruits(fruitList);
      System.out.println("After addFruits :"+fruitList);
}

private static void addFruits(List<String> newfruitsList){
    newfruitsList.add("Papaya");
    newfruitsList.add("Guava");
}
}
```

**Output :**

Before addFruits :[Mango, Banana, Apple]

After addFruits :[Mango, Banana, Apple, Papaya, Guava]

Comment: This is a completely normal behaviour, what exactly is confusing here? `newfruitsList` and `fruitList` reference the same list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is as follow:

```
public class ListAddTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

//you created a new list here.

```
    List<String> fruitList = new ArrayList<String>();

      fruitList.add("Mango");
      fruitList.add("Banana");
      fruitList.add("Apple");
      System.out.println("Before addFruits :"+fruitList);
```

// You are passing the same list to a static function

```
      addFruits(fruitList);
      System.out.println("After addFruits :"+fruitList);
}
```

// The address of the original list is simply copied to `newfruitsList`

```
private static void addFruits(List<String> newfruitsList){
```

// You added the new elements to the `newfruitsList` reference pointing to the same list

```
    newfruitsList.add("Papaya");
    newfruitsList.add("Guava");
}
}
```

To achieve, what you wish

```
public class ListAddTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> fruitList = new ArrayList<String>();
      fruitList.add("Mango");
      fruitList.add("Banana");
      fruitList.add("Apple");
      System.out.println("Before addFruits :"+fruitList);
```

// Create a `newList` out of the original list using `new` operator

```
     List<String> newList= new ArrayList<String>(fruitList);
     addFruits(newList);
     System.out.println("After addFruits :"+fruitList);
     System.out.println("newList:"+newList);
}

private static void addFruits(List<String> newfruitsList){
    newfruitsList.add("Papaya");
    newfruitsList.add("Guava");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A reference means, in effect, the address in memory where the object is located. So you are passing the same list, not a copy of it. If you want a copy of the list then you should copy it to a new list before calling the method. But be careful, a simple copy of the list still contains the same objects (unless you copy them too), so changing an object in the list inside the method will be reflected in the calling program.